# 2-connected iff for every three

Tags: graph-theory

I am having trouble with the following Question:
Prove that a graph is 2-connected(biconnected) iff for every triple distinct vertices u,v,w there is a path connecting u and v and goes through w.
Now , proving $\leftarrow$ is really easy, but I am having trouble proving the $\rightarrow$ part was harder for me and I will be happy if someone could ge me a clue :)
p.s. : our lecturer defined the connectivity of a graph by the number of vertices that need to be removed in order for the graph to become disconnected.

Comment: It may help to think about it in the following way:  You need to prove that you can remove any one vertex and still have a connected graph.  Say you want to get from u to v.  You know in the original graph there was such a path.  Now, you've deleted a vertex--say one on the original path from u to v.  How can you use the property to reconstruct a new path from u to v.

Comment: Ohh oops, I meant that I didn't solve $\rightarrow$ 
the $\leftarrow$ is easy... I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the $\Rightarrow$ direction might require [Menger's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger's_theorem), or a proof equivalent to Menger's theorem.   More specifically, let $G$ be a $2$-connected graph with vertices $u$, $v$, $w$.  Add a vertex $z$ adjacent to $u$ and $v$, and consider Menger's theorem between $w$ and $z$.

Comment: Excellent!! I did't think about adding vertex- it really solves the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be any vertex of $G$.
Let $v,w$ be any two vertices of $G-\{u\}$. Then by assumption, there is a path $u\ldots w\ldots v$ in $G$. Then the part starting at $w$ is a path $w\ldots v$ in $G-\{u\}$. Hence $G-\{iu\}$ is connected for all $u$, thus $G$ is biconnected.

Comment: Yeah yeah , sorry this was easy , I meant that assuminng  iconnectivity  is the part I have hard time solving